# Reading shp using networkx, parallel edges are missing attributes

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, network, graph, networkx

I am trying to use networkx.read_shp to create a MultiGraph from a shape file. I understand that the function needs to be modified since it usually creates a DiGraph I attempt by trying this:

```
def read_multi_shp(path, simplify=True, geom_attrs=True, strict=True):
    try:
        from osgeo import ogr
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("read_shp requires OGR: http://www.gdal.org/")

    if not isinstance(path, str):
        return

    net = nx.MultiGraph() #My first change
    shp = ogr.Open(path)
    if shp is None:
        raise RuntimeError("Unable to open {}".format(path))
    for lyr in shp:
        fields = [x.GetName() for x in lyr.schema]
        for f in lyr:
            g = f.geometry()
            if g is None:
                if strict:
                    raise nx.NetworkXError("Bad data: feature missing geometry")
                else:
                    continue
            flddata = [f.GetField(f.GetFieldIndex(x)) for x in fields]
            attributes = dict(zip(fields, flddata))
            attributes["ShpName"] = lyr.GetName()
            # Note:  Using layer level geometry type
            if g.GetGeometryType() == ogr.wkbPoint:
                net.add_node((g.GetPoint_2D(0)), **attributes)
            elif g.GetGeometryType() in (ogr.wkbLineString,
                                         ogr.wkbMultiLineString):
                for edge in edges_from_line(g, attributes, simplify,
                                            geom_attrs):
                    e1, e2, attr = edge
                    net.add_edge(e1, e2)
                    net[e1][e2][0].update(attr) #Second change and perhaps the one that is not working
            else:
                if strict:
                    raise nx.NetworkXError("GeometryType {} not supported".
                                           format(g.GetGeometryType()))

    return net
```

The rest of the function stays the same. When checking eges I can see that when there are parallel edges one of them seems to have an empty dictionary instead of the attributes (despite these being present in the shapefile). I have seen a similar question before but it seems to be using an outdated version of networkx. Is there any way to make a multigraph that has parallel edges with their attributes?

Comment: A solution to your problem is provided in stackoverflow  [NetworkX - How to create MultiDiGraph from Shapefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30770957/835653)

Comment: Yes, I had seen that, I can do something similar and it will work but it will be multiple directed graph and I was trying to get an undirected one. I suppose converting it after is an option.